# jquery show/hide then scroll to content automatically

Tags: jquery, scroll, show-hide

I found this simple show/hide jquery piece of code at w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle

I don't know how to write any javascript or jquery, but is there a way to add a scrolling action to the script, so when a visitor clicks the button to show the content, it slides it out (which it already does) but also scrolls to that content at the same time?

I have a button at the bottom of my page, and the hidden content appears below it when clicked.

Thanks! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) and [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).
You can pass a function as callback which will execute `scrolltop` after animate.

```
$('.mySlideDiv').click(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle('fast', function() {
        $(window).scrollTop(position);
    });
});
```

Comment: Gave that a go, it worked, however I put my button instead of ".mySlideDiv" and after it scrolled down the button disappeared.

Comment: @JackArrgon of course you have to use your element selector instead of `mySlideDiv`, it's just an example. The other problem I can't help you wthout any code.

Comment: Yeah, just thought I'd make it clear, haha. Alright, here's what I have so far: http://d.pr/n/JL6U

"banner-youtube-videos" is the button to trigger the show/hide. and "master-youtube" is the content below.

Comment: I guess I found a bit of a different solution. Went with a combination of the w3schools code and this http://djpate.com/2011/01/01/animated-scrollto-effect-jquery-plugin/